# CSS hover not doing as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a solution to my problem. I'm not understanding why I'm not getting the result that I need.

I am having trouble with visualizing and understanding the opacity - which is where the problem lays

**I need:**

When a mouse hovers over an image, it tints black (off black).

I'm running into a problem with the second image.

You can see the fiddle with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/FsuKj/

**HTML:**

```
<a class="bg" href=""><img class="portfolio-item" src="https://m1.behance.net/rendition/projects/14633811/404/92f57501037c63b977c220f958145d73.png"></a>
<a class="bg1" href=""><img class="portfolio-item1" src="https://m1.behance.net/rendition/projects/15102955/404/b7ce9b8821177832e8b9eff19854b6d1.png"></a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.portfolio-item, .bg {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    left: 0px;
    border-radius:25px;
    position:absolute;
}

.hover {
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity:0.1;
}
.bg {
    background-color: rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.9);
    top: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.bg1 {
    background-color: rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.9);
    top: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
    left: 225px;
}

.portfolio-item1, .bg1 {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;

    border-radius:25px;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                    $(".portfolio-item").hover(function(){
                        $(".portfolio-item").addClass("hover");
                    }, function(){
                        $(".portfolio-item").removeClass("hover");
                    });

                    $(".portfolio-item1").hover(function(){
                        $(".portfolio-item1").addClass("hover");
                    }, function(){
                        $(".portfolio-item1").removeClass("hover");
                    });

});
```

Thank you!

Comment: it is because of `background-color: pink;`

Comment: Why are you simulating `:hover` using jQuery when this can be achieved using pure CSS? Also, your jQuery can be chopped down to half

Comment: Remove background-color: pink. Also, you were missing closing tag to `img` and also jquery code was inconsistent.  I modified it. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FsuKj/3/).

Comment: @Mr.Alien good point.. If I counter more posts like this.. I will become mad. :)

Comment: @Mr_Green He should use `this` and his job will be done in mere 5 lines...

Comment: @Mr.Alien I agree, my jquery is too long. How would you suggest shortening it? I should use 'this' in the hover functions, but that won't shorten it much at all... suggestions?

Comment: @LiamShalon yes it will, and perhaps you can achieve the above using pure CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `background-color: pink;` in .portfolio-item1, .bg1

```
.portfolio-item1, .bg1 {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute; 
    border-radius:25px;
    /*background-color: pink;*/
}
```

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/FsuKj/4/)

Answer (score 2):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FsuKj/1/)

```
.portfolio-item1, .bg1 {
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
position: absolute;
border-radius:25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

remove this line from css `background-color: pink;`

```
.portfolio-item1, .bg1 {
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
position: absolute;

border-radius:25px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the line background-color: pink;

```
.portfolio-item1, .bg1 {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;

    border-radius:25px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.. Only Remove the background-color: pink;

```
.portfolio-item1, .bg1 
{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius:25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Mr. Alien suggested in above comments, you can do this hovering using just css.

Just change your `.hover` css to `.portfolio-item:hover, .portfolio-item1:hover`

So, this code:

```
.hover {
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity:0.1;
}
```

will become:

```
.portfolio-item:hover, .portfolio-item1:hover {
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity:0.1;
}
```

To know more about `:hover` pseudo class, read this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ahover).

And also the pink tint is coming because you were using `background-color: pink` to `.portfolio-item1, .bg1`. remove it to get black tint which is what I think you need.

```
.portfolio-item1, .bg1 {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;

    border-radius:25px;
    /* background-color: pink; */  /* remove this code */
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FsuKj/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be just to remove the background-color: pink;

But, as Mr.Alien suggested this can be done with pure css. Mr_Green suggested an elegant solution using the psuedo links. Bu, I see a lot of repetitive code in css. You can change that as well like below.

**HTML CODE**

```
<a class="bg" href=""><img class="portfolio-item" src="https://m1.behance.net/rendition/projects/14633811/404/92f57501037c63b977c220f958145d73.png"></a>
<a class="bg1" href=""><img class="portfolio-item1" src="https://m1.behance.net/rendition/projects/15102955/404/b7ce9b8821177832e8b9eff19854b6d1.png"></a>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
.portfolio-item, .bg, .portfolio-item1, .bg1 {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius:25px;
    position:absolute;
}

.portfolio-item, .bg{
    left: 0px;
}

.portfolio-item1:hover, .portfolio-item:hover {
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity:0.1;
}
.bg, .bg1 {
    background-color: rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.9);
    top: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.bg1 {
    left: 225px;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FsuKj/6/)**